# Simout output from sim command called from Matlab Function Block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm trying to simulate a model "inner.mdl" (several timesteps) in one timestep of the root model "outer.mdl". I thought of calling simout = sim("inner.mdl") from a Matlab Function Block. The problem is: Since I'm using extrinsic sim (bypassing code generation), simout is returned as an MxArray and I am unable to retrieve the logged signals from it. Any ideas would be appreciated, whether they are about doing this simulation-in-simulation or with obtaining the logged signals using the method I'm trying.

The main reason I'm doing this is that as part of a controller, I'm trying to simulate the system a few steps ahead in the future to use that information in some way. I don't want to turn my controller into code and even if I get rid of the simulation-time dependent blocks, I don't know how to run a block for some timesteps without the whole model moving forward in time.

Comment: It is very hard to answer a question like this from a general description of what you try to do. Show exactly how you do something and how you fail or be much more specific.

Comment: Jusr write an m-code S-function.  Then you won't have any datatyping issues.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you initialise a variable to `0` or equivalent before having an extrinsic function call that returns this variable, the variable will be of type double rather than MxArray. Not sure if this works for `simout` though, as I seem to remember that `simout` is a structure. Still worth a try.

See [Working with mxArrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html#bq1h2z9-46) in the documentation for more details.